# Why is term been is using in Present Perfect ?

Tags: sentence-construction, present-tense, perfect-constructions

I thought that been in using in Present Perfect Continious only. But i find out
that sometimes it is using in Present Perfect also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "been" can be used as a past participle in Present Perfect in either active voice and passive voice.

For example:
I have been there before. (active)
"been" in here is "be/is/am/are"

It has been used. (passive)
"been" in here is also "be/is/am/are" with another past participle.